# How do you determine your available spell slots as a Wizard/Sorcerer multiclassing?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, multi-classing, sorcerer, spell-slots

When you multiclass as a sorc and a wizard, you add the two classes together and that determines your spell slots. This is one combined table of available slots that both casters share, or does the multiclass wiz/sorc have two spell slots per level, one for each class? Because the second option sound incorrect. They share the same table? Just want to make sure I'm reading this correctly.